# how to create simple website using php,mysql,css,jquery and html?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am new to php. I want to develop a website for some electronic company using php, mysql, jquery, css and html.

Anybody guide me how to start with it? Please give me some examples of website developing using php.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: No offense, but I don't think a beginner should be making websites for Utilities.. not if it's in any way connected to the Utility's network, anyways.

Comment: @jnpcl Exactly my point. Though I think a beginner should not make a website for any company. Learn the profession first and accept jobs afterwards.

Answer (score 11):

Website development is a profession. It is not something you learn in a day. Your question is like: "I want to build a car. Please tell me how can I build a car. Give me an example please.".

If you are really interested in learning webprogramming, forget about "developing" a website for any company (for the sake of all Internet users, please), and give yourself a few months of intensive training.

If you want to start, search SO, it has loads of links to great tutorials. You can also search Google (and please avoid w3schools).

Learn building a simple website using HTML and CSS only first. And I don't mean spending an hour on it and finding out how to turn a word green. Later you can start learning how to output HTML using a programming language (like PHP). Your question have not clarified if you have ever programmed or not, if not, you need to take your time on this. And this is just a quick outline.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how advanced you're looking for...

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/

http://devzone.zend.com/article/627

If you really want to learn PHP, get a good IDE (Eclipse or NetBeans would work), and just start googling "PHP Tutorial".

Shortly you'll find yourself googling more specific things, like "PHP Session Variables", or "PHP Date Addition", etc.  It really is self guiding as to your specific needs.  I would start with the third link in the list above.